publish a message with a floating value and subscriber has a value of 0
Hello i'm writing simple publisher/subscriber code for controlling unitree-B1 robot
I would like to control robot's body height and foot raise height.
so in teleop.py, i defined body_height_publisher, foot_raise_height_publisher. This is how i defined.
body_height_subscriber_ = p_nh_->subscribe("set_body_height_",1, &Base::bodyHeightCallback, this);
foot_raise_height_subscriber_ = p_nh_->subscribe("set_foot_raise_height_",1, &Base::footRaiseHeightCallback, this);

And i published message like that.
            elif key in self.customBindings.keys():
                if key in ['a', 's']:
                    req_body = SetBodyHeight()
                    req_body.value = self.customBindings[key][0]
                    print(req_body.value)
                    self.body_height_publisher.publish(req_body)

                elif key in ['d', 'f']:
                    req_foot = SetFootRaiseHeight()
                    req_foot.value = self.customBindings[key][1]
                    print(req_foot.value)
                    self.foot_raise_height_publisher.publish(req_foot)

This is Subscriber part.
void Base::bodyHeightCallback(const b1_legged_msgs::SetBodyHeight::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::cout << "msg.value : " << msg->value << std::endl;
    robot_high_cmd.bodyHeight += msg->value;
    std::cout << "currently\t body height : " << robot_high_cmd.bodyHeight << std::endl;
}

void Base::footRaiseHeightCallback(b1_legged_msgs::SetFootRaiseHeight msg)
{
    std::cout << "msg.value : " << msg.value << std::endl;
    robot_high_cmd.footRaiseHeight += msg.value;
    std::cout << "currently\t foot raise height : " << robot_high_cmd.footRaiseHeight << std::endl;
}


when i pressed, 'a', and 'd'. teleop.py sends topic to b1_controller node.
i can see somthing happen. but value is missing.
I'd be grateful if you could let me know what the problem is, I'm a newbie so I apologize for my poorly worded question and would appreciate any advice.

If you're having the same problem as me, check your msg or srv for datatypes. In my case, it was int8, so I sent 0.01 and it was resolved to 0.
